# Get value from IDB-Keyval and asxign it to a variable

Tags: javascript, promise, indexeddb, progressive-web-apps

I'm setting a Promise like

```
idbKeyval.set('example', 5)
  .then(() => console.log('It worked!1'))
  .catch(err => console.log('It failed!', err));
```

then, after refreshing page I want to check if this is set and axsign this '5' to variable. Below is code from IDB-Keyval github but I can't get value from it!

```
idbKeyval.get('hello').then(val => console.log(val));
```

Comment: `I'm setting a Promise like` - no, you are not "setting a promise", you are setting something called `example` with the value `5` using whatever idbKeyval is ... and then, you are trying to read a vlaue named `hello` - which possibly doesn't exist, because you've only set a value named `example`

Comment: or, the short version ... `'hello' !== 'example'`

Comment: It is 'promise-based keyval store implemented with IndexedDB'. Syntax comes from https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb-keyval

Comment: whatever, but `'hello' !== 'example'`

Comment: Oh, sorry. I've just coppied it from other page. Obviously I have 

     idbKeyval.get('example').then(val => console.log(val));

Comment: no, it isn't obvious :p

Answer (score 0):

You can see a working example of using `idb-keyval` using `async`/`await` (which simplifies the syntax) at https://jsbin.com/zadarebili/edit?html,output

I can't include a live snippet in Stack Overflow, since the way their embeds work, IndexedDB is blocked, but the relevant code is

```
<body>
  <button id="set">Set</button>
  <button id="get">Get</button>
  <p id="log"></p>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/idb-keyval@2.3.0"></script>
  <script>
    const KEY = 'example-key';
    const VALUE = 'example-value';

    function log(message) {
      document.querySelector('#log').innerText = message;
    }

    async function get() {
      return await idbKeyval.get(KEY);
    }

    async function set() {
      await idbKeyval.set(KEY, VALUE);
    }

    document.querySelector('#set').addEventListener('click', async () => {
      await set();
      log(`Key ${KEY} was saved with value ${VALUE}.`);
    });

    document.querySelector('#get').addEventListener('click', async () => {
      const value = await get();
      log(`Key ${KEY} was read with value ${value}.`);
    });
  </script>
</body>
```